# How to create a chef repo from command line?

Tags: chef-infra

A **chef repo** is used to manage multiple cookbooks, roles, policies, etc. Here is a [chef repo](https://github.com/chef/chef-repo) template. Is there some standard command line way that lets us create the blank chef repo (with all the boilerplate code of course), without having to clone the git repository every time.

There is one to create a cookbook:

```
berks cookbook create <cookbookname>     # Using berkshelf
```

But I am not aware of any such command to create a chef-repo.

Answer (score 4):

I think the official way these days is to get the [Chef DevKit](http://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/).

ChefDK has a command for `chef generate app <chef-repo-name>`. The old method, mentioned below has been deprecated. The github chef-repo directs the user to get ChefDK in the README.

Most [tutorials](http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/first-steps-with-chef.html) suggest something like this and is what I've been doing...

```
root@intro:~# wget http://github.com/opscode/chef-repo/tarball/master
root@intro:~# tar -zxf master
root@intro:~# mv opscode-chef-repo* chef-repo
root@intro:~# rm master
```

I've forked it to my own git repo, so I could customize it with my personal details. A generic method of instantiating the repo is not the best option anyway unless you are making a lot of repos on the same machine.

Comment: yes this is the evident way to do it; similar to cloning except that you are fetching the tarball instead (which takes even more steps infact). (As stated in my question) I am looking for a command like way to do it like: `chef repo create <reponame>`. Something like this would save some user efforts that go into looking for chef-repo template every time and do cloning/fetching, etc and reinitializing git repo.

Comment: The Chef DevKit contains a generate command for the chef-repo.

Comment: Looks good, `chef generate app <chef-repo-name>` command does the job. I have edited your answer to add this info after verifying the command. Once edit is accepted, I'll mark answer as accepted as this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download/install [Chef DevKit](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/)
2. Add chef and ruby to your path (if not already done, see below for more info)
3. `$ chef generate repo chef-repo` (note: last argument is name for your chef repo)

Adding chef/embedded-ruby on your path on mac

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile

$ echo 'export PATH="/opt/chefdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```